# knockout data-bindings on save

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout to modify the  ui. I have the option to remove text from the screen by clicking a close button "x" on each of them.

When i hit save, I want all the remaining text to remain on the screen without the close button and without the input box around the text. How can I achieve this with knockout. My code is below

```js
var data = { Name: "Test",
    Items: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3","DESIGN"]      
};

function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items, function(item) {
        return { value: ko.observable(item) };
    }));
                                    
    self.addItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.removeItem = function(data) { 
        self.Items.remove(data);
    };
    
     self.SaveItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.SaveItem = function(data) { 
        self.Items.save(data);
    };
}
$(document).ready(function() {ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data)); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Items: <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: Items }"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <button data-bind="click: SaveItem">SAVE</button>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: value" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">X</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of slightly changing the snippet in your question, as it was broken. Please do revert my changes if they were wrong.

Comment: Not sure why it appeared broken. I am trying to have when a user clicks save, the close buttons disappear along with the input boxes, but the text remains on the screen only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an observable to tell the view when the items have been saved, then replace the input and "X" with different mark up.

```js
var data = { Name: "Test",
    Items: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3","DESIGN"]      
};

function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.saved = ko.observable(false);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items, function(item) {
        return { value: ko.observable(item) };
    }));
                                    
    self.addItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.removeItem = function(data) { 
        self.Items.remove(data);
    };
    
     self.SaveItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.SaveItem = function(data) { 
         //self.Items.save(data);  I have no idea what you are doing here
         self.saved(true);
    };
}
$(document).ready(function() {ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data)); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Items: <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: Items }"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <button data-bind="click: SaveItem">SAVE</button>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="visible: !$parent.saved()">
            <input data-bind="value: value" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">X</a>
        </td>
       <td data-bind="visible: $parent.saved()">
            <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: what if i would want to add a slider under each item in the array?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by slider.  It is possible.  I use a number of bound sliders in my different applications but there is some overhead to get it to work.  For example your array of strings would have to be changes to an array of objects.  1 prop for string and another for the slider value.  You would also have to do some work to get the slider tied into the ko observable.  I have used custom bindings in the past to do this